# Visual Studio writes code to form1.vb instead of form1.designer.vb

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, designer

For some reason any code generated by the windows forms designer is written to my Form.vb class instead to the Form.designer.vb class where it belongs. I hope you can help me figure out what is causing this.

I removed as much code as possible and was able to reproduce the issue with the following setup:

```
Namespace MyNamespace
public class Form
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
End Namespace
```

This is actually all the code that is left in my form - no methods/ functions/ members. When I remove the Namespace declaration, the code is generated in the Form1.designer.vb file again.

Why does the Namespace interfere with the functionality of Visual Studio?

Comment: I just created a new project from scratch to make sure i don't have any dependencies or settings interfering. I could reproduce this behaviour by just adding "Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form" and an arbitrary Namespace declaration to the autogenerated Form1 class.

Comment: Another remark: The same issue occurs when i generate a new class (not a form) and inherit from System.Windows.Forms.Form manually. In this case no designer.vb class is generated and all code that would belong there is written to my mainclass instead. In This case i don't even need a namespace to obtain this behaviour. This makes me assume though that Visual Studio is in both cases not able to find the proper reference to the designer.vb.

Comment: The designer falls back to legacy VS2002/3 behavior when you do this.  Back when partial classes were not supported yet.  The missing *Partial* keyword in the class declaration is its cue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the Namespace manually to the designer.vb file works for now. However i am not sure if visual studio might remove it during some actions when the designer.vb code is adapted.

Comment: The namespace of all parts of a class in different files must be the same so that the class is considered actually the same class. If you change the namespace in one file, you have to change it also in all other files that make up the class, also in the Designer file. The designer doesn't do that automatically. Otherwise, the class in the designer file makes up a different class than the one in the other file. That's why the designer generates code in the main file, because the other is no longer associated with it.